# Solving $x^2\equiv b \mod p$ for $p$ prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I go about solving $x^2\equiv 116 \mod 587$ for $x$?

I know that 587 is prime. How would I get started?

I know $116= 2^2\cdot 29$

I think if I can solve $116^{147}\mod 587$, then I will have answer?

Comment: You need to find the (square) roots of $b^e\mod m$. That is, those numbers whose square is congruent to $b^e\mod m$.

Comment: This is relevant: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/quadratic_congruences/

Comment: Your exponential version is correct. Now we need to calculate, using modular exponentiation, the binary method or a variant. A little unpleasant, to be sure, but doable with a cheap calculator.

Comment: You are correct: $\pm 116^{147} \bmod 587$ are all the solutions of $x^2\equiv 116\pmod{587}$, and it's simple to prove using [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) and [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity). You can express the answer in this closed exponential form because $587$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$. It would be more difficult if it were a prime of the form $8k+1$. See [this paper](http://course1.winona.edu/eerrthum/13Spring/SquareRoots.pdf) for how to solve $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ with $p$ prime in general.

Comment: I got 65, if that's correct?

Comment: @Jeanie $116^{147}\equiv 65\pmod{587}$. Therefore, all the solutions of $x^2\equiv 116\pmod{587}$ are $x\equiv \pm 65\pmod{587}$, or i.e. $x\equiv \{65,522\}\pmod{587}$.